# Why is the anonymous function and function in Scala constructed like this?

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-function

In [SICP 1.3.2](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3), there is this function

```
(define (f x y)
  ((lambda (a b)
     (+ (* x (square a))
        (* y b)
        (* a b)))
   (+ 1 (* x y))
   (- 1 y)))
```

Now after 30 minutes chasing after errors, I found [this page](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/pl/sicp_scala_01.html) and it provided this function

```
  def f_lambda(x: Int, y: Int) =
    (((a: Int, b: Int) => ((x * square(a)) + (y * b) + (a * b)))
      (1 + (x * y), 1 - y))
```

I do not understand why it is surrounded (like a fort) with parentheses.

Edit: Sorry, my real issue is I don't understand why this function is constructed the way it is. In other words, why are all the parentheses needed in the first place. This looks completely "foreign" compared to the Scala code I've seen so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is certainly possible to eliminate a few of the pairs of parentheses in the particular example you give above, although in the case of the outermost pair, this does require putting part or all of the last line on the end of the preceding line:

```
def f_lambda2(x: Int, y: Int) =
   ((a: Int, b: Int) => (x * square(a) + y * b + a * b))(1 + x * y, 1 - y)
```

That said, you may - as with any code - choose to put in extra parentheses to clarify things (eg. around multiplications to make precedence clearer).

Second, there are alternate ways to write such a function which can make what is going on clearer for any reader. This does mean less brevity of code, but I think the clarity gained can definitely be worth it:

```
def f_lambda3(x: Int, y: Int) = {
  def inner(a: Int, b: Int) = (x * square(a)) + (y * b) + (a * b)
  inner(1 + x * y, 1 - y)
}
```

Overall, just because the most efficient, compact representation of a coding concept might arguably involve bracket madness (yay, Lisp!), this doesn't mean this has to be carried over to Scala, which has many much more accessible constructs for writing exressive code.

Comment: In terms of why the code you show above has been written that way, it looks to me like a mostly-literal translation from Clojure or some other lisp-like language into Scala by someone more familiar with the former than the latter. It makes an interesting change from seeing (sometimes horrifically) Java-styled Scala code from migrants from that language! I would expect that with experience, and exposure to Scala as practised by experts, and answers such as those found here, that such migrants to Scala would learn to produce clearer and more idiomatic translations, as I have attempted here.

Comment: So I obviously fail at being clear. I guess what I'm trying to ask is: what is that construct? Normally there's an expression or expressions wrapped in brackets. But all I see is an anonymous function and its body wrapped in parentheses and then what's supposed to be the body of f_lambda2 wrapped in parentheses immediately afterwards. So I'm just not understanding the construction and how it's all coming together.

Comment: Essentially it is an anonimised version of what I have written for my function `f_lambda3` above (use it as a guide to understand what is being done). There I define a helper function (`inner`), then I call this function, passing in the arguments `1 + x * y` and `1 - y`. Compare this to `f_lambda2` (and your original `f_lambda`): an anonymous function is defined which takes two integers, labelled `a` and `b` (`(a: Int, b: Int)`), and returns a result (`=>`) based on the formula `(x * square(a)) + (y * b) + (a * b)`. This is then immediately called with the arguments `1 + x * y` and `1 - y`.

Comment: To try to clarify further - we have a function from two Ints to Int. This function has the type `(Int, Int) => Int`. The two input Ints are being called `a` and `b`, and the output value is the expression `(x * square(a)) + (y * b) + (a * b)`. Parentheses are required around this whole function definition to delimit where it starts and (more importantly) ends. Then we have another set of parentheses containing the arguments of a call to that function. Hope that makes the notations used clear enough!

Comment: I believe so. This has helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand either. You can strip a few off:

```
def f_lambda(x: Int, y: Int) =
  ((a: Int, b: Int) => (x * square(a)) + (y * b) + (a * b)) (1 + (x * y), 1 - y)
```

Or if you want to rely on the fact that multiplication takes precedence over addition:

```
def f_lambda(x: Int, y: Int) =
  ((a: Int, b: Int) => x * square(a) + y * b + a * b) (1 + x * y, 1 - y)
```

Personally I think the first is a bit more readable.

*Edit:*

Breaking this down a bit, this is declaring an anonymous function which takes two Ints as arguments, styled "a" and "b":

```
(a: Int, b: Int) => x*square(a) + y*b + a*b
```

Note this is still using x and y (being the arguments to the outer method). It is then applying this inner function using a = 1 + xy and b = 1 - y.

So substituting, I believe you end up with:

```
x*square(1 + x*y) + y*(1 - y) + (1 + x*y)*(1 -y)
```

Why not write it this way in the first place (or using an inner function as Shadowland has)? Well, it's a matter of style and context I guess, so I can't really guess the author's initial intention. The point is that Scala is flexible enough to allow lots of different styles by which you can express the same thing.

Comment: Updated, hope this helps a bit.